# Merge NSDictionaries - NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to merge two NSDictionaries:

```
NSDictionary *areaAttributes = [[area entity] attributesByName];
NSDictionary *gpsAttributes = [[gps entity] attributesByName];
NSMutableDictionary *combinedAttributes = [areaAttributes mutableCopy];
[combinedAttributes addEntriesFromDictionary:gpsAttributes];
```

But get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 'The key 'latitude' is not defined for this NSKnownKeysDictionary'
```

`latitude` is a key in `gpsAttributes`

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? Are you sure it happens at merge and not when you call the [gps entity) method?

Comment: Do it crash? if yes can you tell at what point its crashing? It may be XIB instances not properly connected. I am just Guessing.

Comment: @nickfalk @Neelam It's crashing. If I comment out ` [combinedAttributes addEntriesFromDictionary:gpsAttributes];` it doesn't crash.

Comment: @SmoothAlmonds: For future reference, it's usually best to tell people exactly which line the exception comes from. (Also, tell people _how_ you know, by showing the extract from the crash dump file, or explaining how you stepped through in the debugger, or showing the extra log calls you added after each line, or whatever, or people will often spend time getting that information out of you when they could have been helping you.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not dealing with ordinary dictionaries, but with `NSKnownKeysDictionary`, which is an undocumented type that Apple uses in various parts of Cocoa.

If you dump the ObjC class info from the SDK—or, if that sounds too scary, read [someone else's version](https://github.com/yyfrankyy/iOS5.1-Framework-Headers/blob/master/CoreData.framework/NSKnownKeysDictionary.h)—you can see that this is actually a subclass of `NSMutableDictionary`, not just `NSDictionary`, so it's already mutable, so your `mutableCopy` isn't necessary.

More importantly, if you read up on how the [`NSCopying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSMutableCopying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocols are defined, there's nothing that requires `mutableCopy` to return you something that's mutably-compatible with its base class; only that it be mutable, and immutably-compatible with its base class. Which is annoying.

The answer here is to generate a new mutable dictionary, and copy the keys from *both* `NSKnownKeysDictionary` objects into that:

```
NSDictionary *areaAttributes = [[area entity] attributesByName];
NSDictionary *gpsAttributes = [[gps entity] attributesByName];
NSMutableDictionary *combinedAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:20];
[combinedAttributes addEntriesFromDictionary:areaAttributes];
[combinedAttributes addEntriesFromDictionary:gpsAttributes];
```

(Obviously, if you're worried about performance, you either want to tweak that `20`, or get the count of keys from each dictionary and pass in the total. But usually, it doesn't matter.)

You may be wondering why Apple did this. But if you think about it, it's a handy thing. You've got an object that can be used like a C `struct` within the guts of some library, but externally looks just like an `NSDictionary`. (A similar purpose to, e.g., `namedtuple` in Python.) The methods that return them are all designed to return `NSDictionary`, not `NSMutableDictionary`, so nobody's going to know they have a restricted set of keys. Except, of course, if they call `mutableCopy`.

You may also be wondering how you can know about this in advance. Well, you really can't. Either you log the types of the objects, you write an exception handler and log the exception, or you let it crash and find the exception in the crash dump. Or, alternatively, you can be defensive and assume that any dictionary can give you a useless `mutableCopy` and shallow-copy it into a dictionary of a type you control.

Comment: I have to comment that this was one of the most detailed & informative answers I've read on this site. Kudos to abernert.

Comment: Alternatively, `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:knownKeysDictionary]` works instead of `[knownKeysDictionary mutableCopy]`.